# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in bodycenter

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I am generating the following notice in frontend when testing my theme in wp_debug mode.

I can see where the problem is but do not know how to fix this issue?

Error is showing below notice.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/wp-content/plugins/bodycenter-shortcodes/shortcodes-woo/templates/sns_cat_info.php
>   on line 20
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /home/wp-content/plugins/bodycenter-shortcodes/shortcodes-woo/templates/sns_cat_info.php
>   on line 29

```
<?php
$output = '';
$atts = vc_map_get_attributes( 'sns_cat_info', $atts );
extract( $atts );
if( class_exists('WooCommerce') ){
    $uq = rand().time();
    $class = 'sns-cat-info';
    // $class .= ( esc_attr($style) !='' )?' style-'.esc_attr($style):'';
    $class .= ( trim(esc_attr($extra_class))!='' )?' '.esc_attr($extra_class):'';
    $class .= ' '.esc_attr( bodycenter_getCSSAnimation( $css_animation ) );
    if ( $info_want == '3' ) {
        $class .= ' show-btn-shopnow';
    }elseif ( $info_want == '4' ) {
        $class .= ' show-btn-seeall';
    }
    $l_href = $l_name = $l_target = '_self' ;
    if ( $r_type == '1' ){
        $cat_info = get_term_by('slug', $cat, 'product_cat');
        $l_href = get_term_link($cat, 'product_cat');
        $l_name = trim($ctitle) != '' ? $ctitle : $cat_info->name;
        $l_target = '_self';
    }elseif ($r_type == '2' && !empty( $clink ) ) {
        $clink = vc_build_link( $clink );
        $l_href = $clink['url'];
        $l_name = $clink['title'] ? esc_attr( $clink['title'] ) : esc_html__('You should enter title', 'bodycenter-shortcodes');
        $l_target = esc_attr( $clink['target'] ) ;
    }
    $output .= '<div class="'.$class.'">';
    $output .= '<a class="cat-img" href="'.$l_href.'">';
    if($cat_image != ''){
        $cat_image = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $cat_image);
        $img =   wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_image , '');
        $output .= '<img src="'.$img[0].'" alt="'.$l_name.'" />';
    }
    $output .= '</a>';
    $output .= '<div class="cat-info">';
    $output .= '<h4 class="cat-title"><a class="second-font" href="'.$l_href.'" target="'.$l_target.'">'.$l_name.'</a>';
    if ( $info_want == '4' ){
        $output .= '<a class="btn-seeall" href="'.$l_href.'">' . esc_html__('See all', 'bodycenter-shortcodes') . '</a>';
    }
    $output .= '</h4>';
    if ( $info_want == '1' ){
        $output .= '<span class="cat-prd-num">'.$cat_info->count. ' ' . esc_html__('Products', 'bodycenter-shortcodes') .'</span>';
    }else if ( $info_want == '2' ){
        $output .= '<span class="jf-price second-font">' . esc_html__('Just from', 'bodycenter-shortcodes') .' <span class="price-num">'.$jf_price.'</span></span>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    if ( $info_want == '3' ){
        $output .= '<div class="btn-wrap"><a class="btn-shopnow button" href="'.$l_href.'">' . esc_html__('Shop now', 'bodycenter-shortcodes') . '</a></div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Are you the developer of bodycenter-shortcodes? If not, you’re just going to have to report the issue to its developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$cat_info = get_term_by('slug', $cat, 'product_cat');
```

You're trying to get a category by slug, but `$cat` is undefined, so `$cat_info` is `false`, which means that this line:

```
$l_name = trim($ctitle) != '' ? $ctitle : $cat_info->name;
```

Is throwing the first error, because you can't access `->name` on `false`.

And on this line:

```
$l_href = get_term_link($cat, 'product_cat');
```

`$l_href` is becoming a `WP_Error` object because — again — `$cat` doesn't exist. This means that:

```
$output .= '<a class="cat-img" href="'.$l_href.'">';
```

Is throwing the second error, because you're can't concatenate a `WP_Error` object into a string.

Comment: thank for help.

Comment: i added this code but there is new error which is below:--------Notice: Undefined variable: cat_info in /home/wp-content/plugins/bodycenter-shortcodes/shortcodes-woo/templates/sns_cat_info.php on line 18


Notice: Undefined variable: cat_info in /home/wp-content/plugins/bodycenter-shortcodes/shortcodes-woo/templates/sns_cat_info.php on line 20

Comment: That one should be self explanatory. You need to pay attention to what variables you're using and where they're coming from.

Comment: hi jacob peattie, sir i m web designer i do not unerstand php. kindly guide me this is theme which i purchase from theme forest. please help me solve this error. as per your code i made changes and same part of website is showing properly.

Comment: but one section is not working -----------Notice: Undefined variable: cat_info in /home/wp-content/plugins/bodycenter-shortcodes/shortcodes-woo/templates/sns_cat_info.php on line 18

Comment: You _paid_ for this? Get a refund and find another plugin. I'm not doing unpaid work to fix a plugin somebody is charging for.